# moving google chrome cache to RAM in OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-cache

saw an article on lifehacker suggesting using a ramdisk, but wondering if there is a way to do it without going through all of that. (in *nix i believe you can just ln -s to a dir which is created in ram)

alternatively, a way to disable disk cache in chrome in OSX?

Answer (score 3):

You can't control where Chrome stores it's cache, or the size of the cache, from Chrome's UI.
But there are command-line options to control that. See here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=098d42a41aacdc6d&hl=en

And I have yet to find an elegant way to use Chrome command-line options on Mac...

"ln -s" would work on OSX too. So you just need to create a RAM disk anywhere, and replace the cache dir of Chrome with a link to that RAM disk.

Here's how you can create a RAM disk on Mac: http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/